# name exit is not defined in python

Tags: python

The following is the code. 
When I run, I got an error message, saying that "name exit is not defined". Could anyone tell me why? Thanks very much for your time and attention.

```
if len(sys.argv) == 4:
   ### do something
    pass
else:
    print
    "usage: #### something here"
    exit(-1)
```

Comment: Just import sys, like this: from sys import exit; import sys

Comment: you're using `sys.argv`, so clearly, you've imported `sys`. So just do `sys.exit`

Comment: A quick question. I run it earlier with a super computer, and it works. But today I run it in my PC with canopy, it gives me an error like that. Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError: name 'exit' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066518/nameerror-name-exit-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `import sys` first, since `exit` (and `argv`) is in that module.

The error I get when I run your code is:

> File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'sys' is not
>   defined

which is complaining about `sys.argv` instead of `exit`. But in either case, the solution -- `import sys` is the same.

Comment: Actually, even without `import sys` the `exit` command works in terminal. But when I'm running the same script from within Jupyter notebook, I need the import. Not sure why?

Comment: I can't get exit to work anywhere in a running Python3 program even if I import sys.

Answer (score 5):

If you imported `sys` then use `sys.exit(0)` - change `0` with any result code you want to exit with. 
I had the same issue that before compilation when running from `.py` file `exit(0)` worked well but after compiling to `.exe` it gave me an error. I had to change `exit(0)` to `sys.exit(0)` and it worked.

Comment: Bingo! Something about compiling complicates it; adding the `sys.` resolves that.