# NameError: name 'exit' is not defined

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I used cxfreeze to create a Windows executable from planrequest.py. It seemed to work ok, but when I run the exe file I get `NameError: name 'exit' is not defined`

[name exit is not defined in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144893/name-exit-is-not-defined-in-python) states that the fix is to use `import sys`. However, I use import sys. The code runs fine as a python script (as in, I extensively tested the command line arguments before compiling to an executable.)

```
import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("Usage:")
    print("PlanRequest [Request String] [Server IP (optional: assumes 127.0.0.1 if omitted)]")
    exit()

#[do stuff with the request]
```

Comment: `import sys` and then `sys.exit()`

Comment: You need `from sys import exit`, `cxfreeze` removes the `site` initialization which normally sets up `builtins.exit`

Comment: if you `import sys` you should be using `sys.exit`, *but* `exit` should work as well. Do you override it ie have `exit = ...` *anywhere* in your code?

Comment: @AnthonySottile it does? I wonder who thought this would be a good idea.

Comment: @DeepSpace No, that is the only place I use exit.

Comment: @DeepSpace [here's where it gets set up usually](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab025e31abbf9fdb37599dab94507ec429dc3b30/Lib/site.py#L371), (it's been that way since python2.5 at least)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Importing sys will not be enough to make `exit` live in the global scope.

You either need to do

```
from sys import exit
exit()
```

or

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

*Note that, as you are also using argv, in the first case you should do* `from sys import argv,exit`

Comment: This is the answer, and this is truly a pain. If `sys.exit` is required, I feel like the IDE should tell me its required. Maybe I'm just used to more...solidified?...languages.

Comment: A good IDE should tell you one way or another.
In pycharm, if I type

    `import sys`
    then `exit()`

it prints me a warning under the import line "ununsed import statement"

Answer (score 15):

You have to apply the function to sys:

```
from sys import exit
exit()
```

because `exit` is the function itself, you need to call it with `()`